# How to solve this Laplace equation on a semi infinite strip?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Given a Laplace equation with boundary conditions:

> $\frac{\partial^2 u(x, y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x, y)}{\partial y^2}= 0 $, $(0\leq x, 0\leq y\leq 1)$
>
> 1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x, y ) = 0$
> 2. $\frac{\partial u(x, y)}{\partial y}|_{y=0} = 0$
> 3. $u(x, 1) = 0$
> 4. $\frac{\partial u(x, y)}{\partial x}|_{x=0} = 1 + \cos\pi y$

When I tried solving this by assuming $u(x,y)= X(x)Y(y)$, we get by condition $1$ $X(x)= ae^{-kx}$ for some $k>0, a\in \mathbb R$, then by condition $2, 3$, we get $Y(y)=b\cos (ky)$ for some $b\in \mathbb R$ and $k = \frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ where $n$ could be $0, 1, 2, 3...$

But when considering condition 4, write $u=\sum c_nu_n (x, y)$ where $c_n\in \mathbb R$, $u_n(x,y) = e^{-k_nx}\cos(k_ny)$ with $k_n = \frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$, this doesn't seem matching $1+\cos \pi y$, then I'm stucked.

Help please!

Comment: In the last condition you should set $x=0$ after differentiation

Comment: @YuriyS But the right hand side is $\cos(\pi y)$ while the left $\cos(\pi/2+n\pi)$.

Comment: You have a sum with unknown coefficients on the left and a known function on the right. Find the coefficients which would make the condition true. In this case, you can use the properties of Fourier series